# Why do anchor tag disturbs angular behaviour?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular, it happens that this 2 things have a very different behaviour:

```
<li ng-repeat="client in ctrl.client_list">
    <a tabindex="0">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"
            ng-change="console.log(this.checked)"
            ng-model="client.checked">
            {{client.name}}
        </label>
    </a>
</li>
```

And:

```
<li ng-repeat="client in ctrl.client_list">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"
        ng-change="console.log(this.checked)"
        ng-model="client.checked">
        {{client.name}}
    </label>
</li>
```

The only difference is presence of that `<a>` tag. The page is not reloading and model seems to be attached but it doesn't change on click.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: It's invalid HTML markup to have "interactive" elements like checkboxes inside an `<a>` tag.

Comment: @Pointy but I'm replicating how jQuery multiselect plugin works and displays the multiselect dom and it works for them...

Comment: `<label>` elements are also interactive and aren't allowed inside an anchor.

Comment: @Vandervals — Other libraries doing wrong things doesn't mean you should also do wrong things.

Comment: @Vandervals Can you post the tutorial link that you're referencing to?

Comment: Which multiselect plugin are you talking about?

Comment: Maybe I should not use it but they make it work, that is why I wonder why it is not working on this case. The plugin is: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect